# Execute public native method getVmArguments0() from sun.management

Tags: java, c++

I'm trying to execute method `getVmArguments0` from class `sun.management.VMManagementImpl` using JNI, but when i'm using

```
jclass klass = env->FindClass("sun/management/VMManagementImpl");
```

i'm getting an error (Class not found)

How could i execute that native method?

PS I know that correct way is like that:

```
RuntimeMXBean runtimeMxBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
List<String> arguments = runtimeMxBean.getInputArguments();
```

But i don't want to use that method because of security reasons, also is there any other options how to get java input arguments over JNI without executing java methods?

Comment: This is not C++.

Comment: env->FindClass it's JNI and JNI is related to c++